# Expo react-native fetching data from Google API

Tags: javascript, networking, react-native, google-api, expo

I want to obtain data from someone who logged in using his Google account. I am able to login and I receive a token, but I can't fetch the data. It seems that it simply doesn't respond. No error thrown, it just seems to waits

```
async  logIn() {
  try {
    const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
      androidClientId: '645999128246-gv9drk3gtad84ikeifg37p4k5phdu705.apps.googleusercontent.com',
     // iosClientId: '116235701426-lsptd400ahlctrlveoe4vlg96hcjne51.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
    });

    if (result.type === 'success') {
      console.log(result.accessToken);
      getUserInfo(result.accessToken);
      return result.accessToken;
    } else {
      return {cancelled: true};
    }
  } catch(e) {
    return {error: true};
  }
}
 getUserInfo(accessToken) {
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`},
  }).then(res => {console.log(res)});
}
  render() {
  this.logIn();
  (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing an `await` for the call to `this.logIn();` Recommend you read up on Async functions and Promises in JavaScript
2. You are doing heavy network things in a render call, recommend you read up on React performance coding and general organization of react code